# Is the youtube live streaming api still limited to channels with 1000 subscribers?

Tags: youtube-api

I have an application that I'm looking to add live audio/video streaming.

In the IO 13 introduction video they mention that the live streaming API is limited to channels with 1000 subscribers.

I don't have access to such a channel.

However, besides that video, I can't find that restriction in writting anywhere else on the site. I'm hoping it is no longer a problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about YouTube policy.

Answer (score 3):

For developers, YouTube is providing test accounts.

For 1000 subscribers limit, YouTube is working hard to make it more available.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that the 1000 subscriber channel limit is still in place. How long would you guess it will take until it's more available? It's going to take us some time to implement the API anyways. Once we are running we will be streaming multiple hour long events everyday. What kind of restrictions does the developer test accounts have?

Comment: Now the limit is 100 subs. We hope to make it more available in future.